# ODI: KM Java BeanShell - escape double quotes

Tags: oracle, oracle-data-integrator

I want to set a variable inside Knowledge Module's Task, with target technology set to Java BeanShell. The value represents mapping EXPRESSIONs, where source table is inside MSSQL database. Column names are surrounded by double quotes, that causes a problem with templating.

Column expression is:

```
source_tab."Entry Number"
```

Task (Java BeanShell)

```
<$
   String SEL_COLS = "<%=odiRef.getColList(0, "", "[EXPRESSION]\t[ALIAS_SEP] [CX_COL_NAME]", ",\n\t", "", "")%>";
$>
```

This variable assignment fails, because " in source_tab."Entry Number" is not escaped - code does not compile.

odiRef.getQuotedString does not solve the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`odiRef.getQuotedString` could help if generated code is executed as a final code in JBS technology. When we use it in the following way (in ?-, $- or @-substitution):

```
<$
String SEL_COLS = <%=odiRef.getQuotedString(odiRef.getColList(0, "", "[EXPRESSION]\t[ALIAS_SEP] [CX_COL_NAME]", ",\n\t", "", ""))%>;
$>
```

then result fails like this:

```
... Caused by: org.apache.bsf.BSFException: BeanShell script error: 
Parse error at line 3, column 37.  Encountered: Entry BSF info: ....
... 11 more

Text: <$
   String SEL_COLS = "SOURCE_TAB.\"Entry Number\"      ENTRY_NUMBER";
$>.
```

This looks good but does not work. It could work as final code (I mean result of all substitutions) in JBS Technology. Unfortunately any substitutions eats backslashes.

Ok, if standard odiRef-functtion does not work, lets write our own:

```
<%
String getQuotedStringCustomized(String s){
   return '"'+s.replaceAll('"'.toString(),'"'+"+'"+'"'+"'+"+'"')+'"';
}
%>
-- other code........
<$
String SEL_COLS = <%=getQuotedStringCustomized(odiRef.getColList(0, "", "[EXPRESSION]\t[ALIAS_SEP] [CX_COL_NAME]", ",\n\t", "", ""))%>;
$>
```

Only the way to put `"` into a Java literal within the JBS Substitution is contatenation with Char literal `'"'` or using `'"'.toString()` expression if it is impossible to use Char type.

FINALLY:

In final JBS code you may use `\"`, but within substitutions only `+'"'+`.

Comment: Concatenating double quote as a character pointed me in a right direction. My case changes a bit, and I actually had to escape double quote inside the char itself like '\"'. I really don't like how ODI handles this - sometimes templating generally feels like shooting yourself in a leg.

Comment: Single quote is Char literal. So, only one symbol can appear inside. E.g. `'X'` is correct, but `'AB'` is wrong.
If you use `'\"'` then it is equivalent to `'"'` (without backslash). Like explained above ODI "eats" backslashes within JBS-substitutions.
It happens bacause of source code processing. 
ODI always translate everything into JBS-code which prints you code again, and real execution goues after that.

Comment: Therefore, how can I tell the beanshell to actually execute a code which must contain a double quote inside a string?